# Initialise an unsafe fixed double array in struct

Tags: c#, unsafe

This question is a follow up from [Marshalling C# structure to C++ Using StructureToPtr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747330/marshalling-c-sharp-structure-to-c-using-structuretoptr). 
I have the following struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Size = 120, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public unsafe struct DynamicState
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public fixed double Position[3];

    [FieldOffset(24)]
    public fixed double Velocity[3];

    [FieldOffset(48)]
    public fixed double Acceleration[3];

    [FieldOffset(72)]
    public fixed double Attitude[3];

    [FieldOffset(96)]
    public fixed double AngularVelocity[3];
}
```

If I try and initialise an array like this:

```
var dynamicState = new DynamicState();
double[] array = new double[] { 1, 2, 3 };

fixed (double* pArray = array)
{
    dynamicState.Acceleration = pArray;
}
```

I get the following error:`The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer`.

What is the correct way to initialise an unsafe array that is part of a struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the simple approach seems to *work*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    dynamicState.AngularVelocity[i] = array[i];
}
```

It may not be as far as you're looking for though. Is this a performance-critical piece of code?

This *may* be better:

```
Marshal.Copy(array, 0, new IntPtr(dynamicState.AngularVelocity), array.Length);
```

I can't say I've much experience with unmanaged code, but it's worth at least looking at those options...

Comment: It is performance sensitive. However will the compiler optimize that with dynamicstate being unsafe?

Comment: He may PInvoke `C memset` function. It is so fast (although it is not very good with floating-point numbers)

Comment: @Seth: I don't like to guess too much with optimizations :) See whether the second one works for you - it may well be faster.